# Prompting a user for information to create 2 objects using the constructor given

Tags: c#, constructor

I have 3 classes, Insurance, Employee and InsuranceTest.

Insurance calls the Employee class and the InsuranceTest must test the code by Prompting a user for information to create 2 objects using the constructor given.

Insurance Code Class:

```
namespace IT
{
    class Insurance
    {
        private int cust;

        private string agent;
        string state;

        public Insurance (int cust, string agent, string state )
        {
            this.cust = cust;
            this.agent = agent;
            this.state = state;
        }
        public Insurance ( int cust, string agent) 
            : this( cust,  agent, "")
        {
        }
        public int Cust 
        {
            get { return cust; }
            set { cust = value; }
        }

          public string Agent 
        {
            get { return agent; }
            set { agent = value; }
        }
        public string State
        {
            get { return state; }
            set { state = value; }
        }

        Employee e1 = new Employee("Susi", "Insurance Agent Ave SW", 77582);
    }
}
```

Employee Class [Insurance Class calls this class with the information):

```
namespace IT
{
    class Employee
    {
        string name;
        string address;
        private int id;

        public Employee(string name, string address, int id)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
            this.id = id;
        }
        public Employee(string name, string address) 
            : this( name,  address, 0)
        {
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get { return address; }
            set { address = value; }
        }
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

InsuranceTest Class (**Code I am struggling with**, it must **Prompt** a user for information to create 2 objects using the **constructor** [assuming employee and Insurance class] given while displaying agent information, number of customers, local state

```
namespace IT
{
    class InsuranceTest
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Insurance i1 = new Insurance(5, "Random Insurance", "PA");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"I spark up a problem."` What is the problem? This description unfortunately does not spark any understanding...

Comment: When it comes to InsuranceTest Class, I called the insurance class Insurance i1 = new Insurance(5, "Random Insurance", "PA");

but when I get to the Console.WriteLine part, i1.SetCustomers(0);
            Console.WriteLine(i1.GetCustomers());  I am told that SetCustomers does not exist. Also, I have no understand of c#. I'm super new to this, clearly. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the comments, your SetCustomers method doesnt exist. You can simply do this:

```
i1.Cust = 10; // you can use non zero value instead of 0 to see if Cust is set
```

To print the cust, you can simply do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(i1.Cust);
```

MSDN on C# getter and setter and properties is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties